# The API design philosophy in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

After learning OCaml for like half year, I am still struggling at the `functional programming` and `imperative programming` bits.

It is **not** about `using list or array`, but about API design.

For example, if I am about to write `stack` for a user, should I present it in `functional`  or `imperative` way?

`stack` should have a function called `pop`, which means return the last element to user and remove it from the stack. So if I design my `stack` in `functional` way, then for `pop`, I should return a tuple `(last_element, new_stack)`, right? But I think it is ugly.

At the same time, I feel `functional` way is more natural in Functional Programming.

**So, how should I handle this kind of design problem?**

---

**Edit**

I saw `stack`'s source code and they define the type like this:

```
type 'a t = { mutable c : 'a list }
```

Ok, internally the standard lib uses `list` which is immutable, but the encapsulate it in a mutable record.

I understand this as in this way, for the user, it is always one stack and so no need for a tuple to return to the client.

But still, it is not a functional way, right?

Comment: Perhaps you can have `pop` returning the pair, `top` returning the element, and `drop` returning the substack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mutable structures are sometimes more efficient, but they're not persistent, which is useful in various situations (mostly for backtracking a failed computation). If the immutable interface has no or little performance overhead over the mutable interface, you should absolutely prefer the immutable one.

Comment: but in my question, then for function `pop`, it would have to return a tuple, will that look nice?

Comment: I think returning a tuple is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Functionally (i.e. without mutability), you can either define it exactly like `List` by using head/tail rather than pop, or you can, as you suggest, let the API handle state change by returning a tuple.  This is comparable to how state monads are built.

So either it is the responsibility of the parent scope to handle the stack's state (e.g. through recursion), in which case stacks are exactly like lists, or some of this responsibility is loaded to the API through tuples.

Here is a quick attempt (pretending to know O'Caml syntax):

```
module Stack =
  struct
    type 'a stack = 'a list
    let empty _ = ((), [])
    let push x stack = ((), x::stack)
    let pop (x::stack) = (x, stack)
      | pop _ = raise EmptyStack
  end
```

One use case would then be:

```
let (_, st) = Stack.empty ()
let (_, st) = Stack.push 1 Stack.empty
let (_, st) = Stack.push 2 st
let (_, st) = Stack.push 3 st
let (x, st) = Stack.pop st
```

Instead of handling the tuples explicitly, you may want to hide passing on `st` all the time and invent an operator that makes the following syntax possible:

```
let (x, st) = (Stack.empty >>= Stack.push 1 >>=
               Stack.push 2 >>= Stack.push 3 >>= Stack.pop) []
```

If you can make this operator, you have re-invented the state monad. :)

(Because all of the functions above take a state as its curried last argument, they can be partially applied. To expand on this, so it is more apparent what is going on, but less readable, see the rewrite below.)

```
let (x, st) = (fun st -> Stack.empty st >>= fun st -> Stack.push 1 st
                                        >>= fun st -> Stack.push 2 st
                                        >>= fun st -> Stack.push 3 st
                                        >>= fun st -> Stack.pop) []
```

This is one idiomatic way to deal with state and immutable data structures, at least.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But one question is should I do this as you said? I mean is this a nice way / best way to present stack to the user client?

Comment: When designing an API, I suppose you should look at what it builds up against.  If all the places that expect to call this Stack module are written imperatively, monadic code will stick out.  As an advocate of the functional style I would still prefer consistency.

Comment: Community wiki means that other people can edit my post.  In case I made an error, I wanted it to be easy for others to fix it.

Comment: I guess in your suggestions, tuple is necessary only for `pop`, right? for `push` `empty` etc, we just need the new stack returned

Comment: Yes, `push` would only return a stack and not a tuple. I usually leave `push` for immutable types and use `add` instead. Like in `set` and `map`.